# How to use the ready slider (slick)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to use a ready-made slider in the form of a WordPress site that I have designed for myself. For this purpose, I have used the following site ready sliders:
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I want to use (Slider Syncing) among the ready sliders of this site, but I can't fix the HTML part.

[image]

**All the codes I have used for this slider:**

```js
 $('.slide_big').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            fade: true,
            asNavFor: '.slide_content'
        });
        $('.slide_content').slick({
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            asNavFor: '.slide_big',
            dots: true,
            centerMode: true,
            focusOnSelect: true
        });
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;
}


.slick-slide {
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
    opacity: .2;
}

.slick-active {
    opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide_big img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}

.slide_content img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




  <section class="MyClass slider">
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally used slick slider for many years. Great stuff.

So I can see you have trouble understanding how to declare what should be a slider.

The $('.class-here').slick() in the jQuery part refers to the parent wrapper of the slides, not the slides themself.

So in order to make a slick slider, you would have to declare the wrapper of the slides here.

Now in order to make the slider syncing work, you need 2 sliders. 1 being the main and one being the navigation slider.

I have edited your code to do this exactly.

Inspect it and you will find I have created 2 parent wrappers and in the jQuery, they are linked with the "asNavFor".

I hope it makes sense, if not, then feel free to ask.

Good luck!

```js
$('.slider_main').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider_nav',
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
});
$('.slider_nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider_main',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;
}


.slick-slide {
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
    opacity: .2;
}

.slick-active {
    opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide_big img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}

.slide_content img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




  <section class="MyClass slider_main">
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        </section>
        <section class="slider_nav">
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_big slider">
             <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide_content">
            <img src="https://cbpacs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Bhediya-Movie-Download-1024x544.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
```